# Open an iframe with a URL and then run some JS

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, electron

I'm building an app using Atom Shell, and I'm trying to open an iframe which would load a PDF file, and then, once the PDF file is fully loaded, run some JS from the scope of that iframe (I'm willing to run `Browser->Print (https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowprintoptions)`.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where the PDF file is hosted, but usually the process goes like this:

1. create a new browser window object with the size/configs desire for you 'iframe' that isn't going to be an actual iframe
2. `.show()` the browser window
3. `.loadUrl(INSERT_PDF_URL)` into the browser window
4. listen on browser window `webContents` `'did-finish-loading'` event, and then either run your JS if it is on the browser side, or `.executeJavaScript(YOUR_JS_HERE)` if you need it to be run on the renderer side (within the browser window)